# google spreadsheet importxml and continue

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I do simple spreadsheet for my target - monitoring prices in Eve Online market. I use eve-central api and try import data from it.
I use importXML function:

```
=(ImportXML(CONCATENATE(Sys!$B$4;A1;Sys!$C$4);"//sell/min"))
```

where: `CONCATENATE(Sys!$B$4;A1;Sys!$C$4` - formatting url adress.

How you can see I recieved data from eve-central, but I can't translate this data to number format.

I tried to use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ImportXML(CONCATENATE(Sys!$B$4;A1;Sys!$C$4);"//sell/min");".";",")
```

but it failed. I tried using `=CONTINUE` function, but it's incorrect - this function doesn't exist(???).
How can I receive data from eve-central, and work with this data as value?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you doing since we can't see what the url address you're using is. Here's a simple price DB sheet that I use.

- Column A is the item name
- Column B is the item ID number.
- Column C has: =ImportXML("http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=" & $B2 & "&usesystem=30000142", "//sell")

This pulls in all the sell data for whatever item ID was in B2 and only for the Jita system (30000142). The sell data is actually 7 pieces of data put in the next 7 columns.

- Column C is volume (total number of items up for sell orders I believe).
- Column D is average sell price of all sell orders.
- Column E is highest sell order price (Max).
- Column F is lowest sell order price (Min).
- Column G is the standard deviation of prices.
- Column H is the median price.
- Column I is the percentile.

I then use vlookups to pull this data to other spreadsheets.